# Bacteria utilize short chain fatty acid as energy source

Tags: microbiology, metabolism, gut-bacteria

I'm doing research about the short chain fatty acid producing bacteria. I studied 7 short chain fatty acid (acetic propionic butyric isobutyric valeric isovaleric and captionic). and I found that the bacteria produced all acid in 8-12 hr incubation time  and after that all short chain fatty acid rapidly decreased, except acetic acid slightly decreased. How can I explain this results?  and I did my experiment under anaerobic condition.